# Get current userId in controller when getuserId function is not present

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

Using Aspnet Identity 2.0. I need to access currently logged in user details from HomeController. When i write

```
User.Identity...
```

It has the following options only

- IsAuthenticated
- AuthenticationType
- Name

There is no GetUserId() function and this is an object of type

> System.Security.Principal.IIdentity IPrincipal.Identity

**Background on my project**
I have re-arranged the default classes into different projects.

**ABC.Web**

- AccountViewModels.cs
- AccountController.cs
- ApplicationUserMAnager

  ```
  public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
  {
  public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int> store)
      : base(store)
  {
  }

  public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
  {
      var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser, Role, int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
      // Configure validation logic for usernames
      manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser, int>(manager)
      {
          AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
          RequireUniqueEmail = true
      };
      // Configure validation logic for passwords
      manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
      {
          RequiredLength = 6,
          RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
          RequireDigit = true,
          RequireLowercase = true,
          RequireUppercase = true,
      };
      // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
      // You can write your own provider and plug in here.
      manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("PhoneCode", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>
      {
          MessageFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
      });
      manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>
      {
          Subject = "Security Code",
          BodyFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
      });
      manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
      manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
      var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
      if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
      {
          manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, int>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
      }


      return manager;
  }
  }
  ```

**ABC.Entities**

- ApplicationUser
- Role
- UserClaim
- UserLogin
- UserRole

  ```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
   {
   public virtual User user { get; set; }


  public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
  {
      // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
      var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
      // Add custom user claims here
      return userIdentity;
  }
  }
  ```

**ABC.Core**

- ApplicationDbContext
- USerStore
- RoleStore

Comment: Please add this namespace and try once, using System.Security.Principal;

Comment: Nope i still cannot access User.Identity.GetUserId() and btw it is not even defined in IIdentity interface